# Insert multiple rows based off condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to insert multiple rows where each row has the same `environment_id`, however, it has different `property_id`. Something similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO appserver_prop (environment_id, property_id)
VALUES (497, select property_id from prop_info where property_name like '%CPNIB%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use :

```
insert into appserver_prop(environment_id, property_id)
select 497, property_id from prop_info where property_name like '%CPNIB%'
```

*you don't need `values` clause, since you're not trying to insert a single record in SQL but multiple record set instead.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into appserver_prop (environment_id, property_id)
    select 497, property_id
    from prop_info
    where property_name like '%CPNIB%';
```

Comment: @Robin - You would do well to mark one of the answers as the CORRECT answer. In this case, two identical answers were posted almost simultaneously. It appears that Gordon's answer was first (by a few seconds), so it should probably get the Correct Answer mark.

Comment: @mathguy I did "ini mini miny moe" to determine the accepted answer :).